# How can "jemand muss funktionieren" be translated to english?

Tags: idioms, translation, german

The german term

> Jemand muss funktionieren

is often used to express that somebody has to continue doing his stuff (work, house work, ...) because otherwise there are negative consequences (e.g. for his children) which are not an option for him. The term is often used by persons who have to raise their children alone and have a high pressure such that they merely can do things they want to do.

However, the literal translation

> Somebody has to work

seems to have a different meaning...i.e. (translated back)

> Jemand muss arbeiten

So how can I translate it without changing the meaning?

Comment: One maybe related phrase is "keep on keepin' on".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might not be exact, but there’s the expression *you have to do what you have to do*:

> [*You got to do what you got to do*](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/You+got+to+do+what+you+got+to+do)
>   One has to do whatever it is that one feels obliged to do. *I know I wouldn't ever agree to that kind of thing, but you got to do what you got to do.*
>   (TFD)

It’s also spoken as *you gotta do watcha gotta do*.

I don’t think it exactly suggests that there will be negative consequences. But it can suggest that you have no other options.

*Example.*

> A: Wow, I can’t believe you picked up another shift!
>   B: You gotta do watcha gotta do to put food on the table.

You can imagine B being a hard-working parent, single or not.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few similar English expressions you could use in various circumstances:

> - (It's hard work, but) somebody's got to do it. *(~ Jemand muss es tun.)*
> - You do what you have/need to do. *(~ Man tut was mann tun muss.)*
> - X won't Y itself. (The kids won't raise themselves. The bills won't pay themselves.)